# Outlook Sorting Attachments by key phrase

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run some VBA code to automatically save attachments based on a phrase in the attachment name to specific folders on my desktop.

```
   Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If objAtt.SaveAsFile = "Test1" Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test1"
        If objAtt.SaveAsFile = "Test2" Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test2"
        If objAtt.SaveAsFile = "Test3" Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test3"
        If objAtt.SaveAsFile = "Test4" Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test4"
        If objAtt.SaveAsFile = "Test5" Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test5"
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

It is probably more long winded then it needs to be, but I am hoping you get the idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you say "phrase in the attachment name" do you mean something like "FileNamedTest1.ext" should match "Test1"?  If that's the case, you can just replace `= "Test1"` with `Like "*Test1*"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instr will indicate whether the phrase is in the Displayname.

```
Private Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As mailItem)

    Dim objAtt As attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

        saveFolder = ""
        Debug.Print objAtt.DisplayName

        If InStr(LCase(objAtt.DisplayName), LCase("Test1")) > 0 Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test1"
        End If

        If InStr(LCase(objAtt.DisplayName), LCase("Test2")) > 0 Then
            saveFolder = "P:\Desktop\Reports\Test2"
        End If

        ' ....

        If saveFolder <> "" Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        Else
            MsgBox "No match. " & objAtt.DisplayName & " not saved."
        End If
    Next

    If objAtt Is Nothing Then
         Debug.Print "objAtt is already Nothing."
    Else
        MsgBox "Somehow objAtt was not nothing."
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```